How to add an Ubuntu app shortcut to my Windows Start menu in WSL?
I installed several apps in Ubuntu WSL. Initially, the app shortcuts were automatically added to the Windows Start menu. However, after installing new apps, the shortcuts were no longer added, and now I have to open them manually in the Ubuntu terminal. How can I add them manually to the Windows Start menu? For example, GNU Radio.


This seems like Windows 11 malfunction rather than a problem with Ubuntu.

@user68186 I have windows 10, but perhaps is the same problem in windows 11

My bad, I assumed the GUI apps in WSL was only available in Windows 11. Needless to say, I don't use WSL at all and very little Windows.

I am not an expert on this subject but given that there haven't been any other answers yet I'm willing to spitball -- can you create a shortcut that calls WSL with arguments that are a linux command to run the desired app?  I'm thinking something like wsl /usr/bin/apt update (although I assume you want to run something more interesting than apt update).
I'm having a hard time finding a super definitive source on this, but this blog at the very end has a section that seems to suggest this method should work, and I'm seeing this referenced in other Stack Exchange questions as well.
